# Can't get a DataGrid to update

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WPF Toolkit `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `Car` in my view model.  `Car` has a `PropertyChanged` event and the setters of each of its two string properties fire the event.  I also have the grid's `SelectedItem` property bound to a property in the view model of type `Car`, also called `SelectedItem`.

On the same window as the grid, I have buttons for `add`, `modify` and `delete`.  `Add` and `modify` open a dialog window with two textboxes, one for each `Car` property.  `Delete` just shows a confirm dialog then does the delete.

For `add` and `delete`, I add or delete an item from the `ObservableCollection` and the grid updates itself as expected.  However, for `modify` it does not.  At first, my `Car` did not use `PropertyChanged` and after some searching I found that it needed to for the grid to update when an individual item's properties changed.  But now that I am using `PropertyChanged`, the grid still doesn't update.

I've tried changing the values of the `SelectedItem` in my view model as well as directly changing the item on the collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and not just raising a PropertyChanged event. Also, when raising PropertyChanged, you must pass "this" as the sender, otherwise WPF will ignore the event.

Below is a simple base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string name;

    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { 
            if (name != value) {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Josh - I was raising the event but not implementing the interface. Duh :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic problem with ObservableCollection. ObservableCollection only notifies of additions, deletions, etc. on it's self.  It will NOT notify of changes to properties of whatever you have stored in it. This is why  your add/delete operations work as expected.

What you should do is use a CollectionView and bind to that:

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();    
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection);
```

using this method also has the benifit that grouping and sorting are built into the view.